# Cursor Movement Cell to Cell Responsive Table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

We have a requirement to move the cursor from one editable cell to another automatically in sap.m.table .

I tried all the previously answered blogs but none of the code works.

Has anyone tried similar requirement before ?

Thanks

Tisha

Answer (score 0):

I had this requirement before. I had to automatically focus from input field in column A to the next input field in column C in my sap.m.Table.

How I solved it was like this:
I detected the change of my input A by defining an event handler on the view XML. Then I get by id the input C and use jQuery method to put focus on its HTML inner element.